# WiFi Drivers for Galaxy Tab Pro S and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Galaxy Tab Pro S.  Unfortunately the Wi-Fi is not working and I would like some assistance on how to get it going.

Thank you for any assistance you provide

As requested here is network info -

Galaxy-TabPro-S-LTE:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -a3
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)

```
Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [144d:c135]
Kernel modules: i2c_i801
```

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)

```
Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [144d:c135]

Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Galaxy-TabPro-S-LTE:~$

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact wireless device. Please open a terminal and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Next, edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: May we also see: `rfkill list all` as well as: `dmesg | grep ath`